# How to run a Dash app with threading and with debug=True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, plotly-dash, python-multithreading

This demo app runs a python process with a [Plotly / Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/) user interface. When it starts Dash with `app.run_server(debug=True)` the following error is raised:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (dashfun):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()

. . . some more source files threading --> dash --> flask --> werkzeug . . .

  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/signal.py", line 56, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
```

The program starts two threads, one running Dash and the other which does the actual work. Two queues, one to transfer commands to the process, one to respond to Dash queries.

Suggestions on how to fix this problem and/or how to add a Dash user interface to a program that is running in the background is appreciated.

Here is the program:

```
''' Dash in Thread
'''

import time
import queue
import threading
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, callback, Output, Input, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

# Make queues
comqueue = queue.Queue() # commands from dash to process
respqueue = queue.Queue() # response from process to dash

# Dash Function
def dashfun(comqueue, respqueue):
    app = Dash('ThreadTest')
    app.layout = html.Div([
        html.H1('Dash Thread Test'),
        dcc.Interval(id='valsinter', interval = 2000, n_intervals=0),
        html.Slot(id='valsout'),
        html.Div(['Set Delta: ',
                  dcc.Input(id='deltain', type='number', value = 0.0, debounce=True),
                  html.Slot(id='dump')])
    ])

    @callback(
        Output('valsout','children'),
        Input('valsinter','n_intervals'),
        State('valsout','children')
        )
    def update_value(n,value):
        print('Update_Value ' + repr(value))
        try:
            # WARNING: This won't work if more than one dash is open
            resp = respqueue.get(timeout = 0.01)
            print('dash - got resp = '+resp)
        except queue.Empty:
            resp = None
        if resp:
            value = 'Value = %.2f' % float(resp.strip())
        return value

    @callback(
        Output('dump','children'),
        Input('deltain','value')
        )
    def new_delta(delta):
        print('New Delta: ' + repr(delta))
        comqueue.put('%.2f' % delta)
        raise PreventUpdate
        return repr(delta)
    
    app.run_server(debug=True) # Debug doesn't seem to be working :-\

# Process function
def profun(comqueue, respqueue):
    value = 0.0
    delta = 0.1
    while True:
        # Check for new delta in command queue
        try:
            resp = comqueue.get(timeout = 0.01)
            print('process - got command = '+resp)
        except queue.Empty:
            resp = None
        if resp:
            delta = float(resp.strip())
        # Update value, print and send to response queue
        value += delta
        print('Val = %.1f' % value )
        respqueue.put('%.2f' % value)
        time.sleep(4.0)

# Start threads
dthread = threading.Thread(target = dashfun, args = (comqueue, respqueue))
pthread = threading.Thread(target = profun, args = (comqueue, respqueue))

dthread.start()
pthread.start()
```

The program runs mostly fine with `app.run_server(debug=False)`. But when a client connects it still raises the error:

```
Error importing optional module IPython.core.display
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_plotly_utils/optional_imports.py", line 30, in get_module
    return import_module(name)

. . . importlib --> IPython --> futures . . .

  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1504, in _register_atexit
    raise RuntimeError("can't register atexit after shutdown")
RuntimeError: can't register atexit after shutdown
```

The goal is to run without errors and in Dash `debug=True` mode with Dash running in a thread.

When running `dashfun(comqueue,respqueue)` in the main thread (instead of using a second thread for Dash), it seems to work without `debug=True`. With `debug=True` and `dashfun()` in the main thread there seem to be two pthreads running at the same time.

Comment: e-dervieux had the same question on: https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/issues/952 . This may be a Flask issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Sanskar Biswal](https://github.com/sanskarbiswal) on github answered the question at [plotly/dash-core-components/issues/952#issuecomment-2015163046](https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/issues/952#issuecomment-2015163046) :

Quoting him:

Try using the following

`app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)`